# How to change the font family of Highchart to Bootstrap css default font family

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, highcharts

I want to change the font of **title**, **data label** and **tooltip** to Bootstrap default default font in the pie chart (I'm using Highchart library to show the chart). I'm How can I change these? Tried to add fontFamily but it didn't work.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: $(element).attr('id'),
                        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: "Space Used by Users",
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{point.name}: {point.sizeText}',
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '11px'
                                }
                            },
                            showInLegend: true
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.sizeText}</b>'
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name: 'Personal Usage',
                                y: scope.item.personalUsage,
                                sizeText: scope.item.personalUsageSizeText
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Shared Usage',
                                y: scope.item.sharedUsage,
                                sizeText: scope.item.sharedUsageSizeText
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
                });
```

How to change the font to default bootstrap?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are only setting the font for the chart title. The below code sets the font globally for the pie chart.

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica'
        }
    }
   });
```

Comment: can you tell me the default font used in twitter bootstrap?

Comment: font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

Comment: it's set to bold by default. How to change it to normal? tried `font-weight: normal` but it doesn't work

Comment: got it. `fontWeight: 'normal'` did the job